# '__builtin_address of': identifier not found when running opencv in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I am try to run simple Canny Edge in Visual Studio 2015 but I failed to run it.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C3861   '__builtin_addressof': identifier not found Canny Edge  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstddef  725

I do not think this error is due to linking problem and this project is workable project which I did last time. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I suspect that you somehow managed to mix a later (Update 3?) standard library with an earlier (say, Update 2) compiler.

Comment: then what is the possible solution?

Comment: @T.C. You are correct. when i repair the visual studio, i found out visual c++ version in my computer newer than the one in setup. I uninstalled it and repair it again and it works.

Comment: I ran into this today.  Installed VS2015 Community with Update 2.  Checking the Application Event Log revealed that the installer bumped me to Update 3 at some point in the installation process.  Haven't spent the time to track down why that is, but I've been setting up a dev environment with lots of different compiler versions, so anything could happen. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem with **__builtin_addressof** and I solved it.

1. Open the About in the Visual Studio 2015.
2. If there is an **Update 3**, close the Visual Studio 2015.
3. Open the Programs and Features in the Control Panel.
4. Right click on your Microsoft Visual Studio ... 2015 in the list and choose Change.
5. In the wizard choose **Repair** and continue... (It is long-running operation, I have SSD and i5 and it took several hours.)

Comment: Had an issue installing gulp-sass via npm, and ran into this problem. Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: A repair was not enough for me.  I had to uninstall Visual Studio.  When I reinstalled, I noticed that in the "Custom" section there is an option to install Update 3, which is ON by default!  It was the very first option in the list.  I unchecked that, installed, and all my problems melted away!

Answer (score 0):

I just lost half a day to this issue.  The [answer from Martin Šulc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230171/1553090) works for some people, but not for me.  This is what I had to do:

- Uninstall Visual Studio 2015
- Run the installer, select *Custom*
- **Uncheck** the *Visual Studio 2015 Update 3* option (it's at the top):

  [image: custom install]

My version is VS 2015 Community with Update 2.  With this release at least, it seems that Update 3 is installed by default even though the installer is based on Update 2...

But are you *actually* surprised? ;)